# byte[] to byte* in C#

Tags: c#, types, multilingual, primitive-types

I created 2 programs - in C# and C++, both invoke native methods from **C** dll. C++ works fine, because there are the same data types, C# doesn't work.

And native function parameter is `unsigned char*`. I tried `byte[]` in C#, it didn't work, then I tried:

```
fixed(byte* ptr = byte_array) {
  native_function(ptr, (uint)byte_array.Length);
}
```

It also doesn't work. Is it correct to convert byte array to `byte*` in such way? Is it correct to use byte in C# as `unsigned char` in **C**?

EDIT:
This stuff returns the wrong result:

```
byte[] byte_array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source_string);
nativeMethod(byte_array, (uint)byte_array.Length);
```

This stuff also returns the wrong result:

```
 byte* ptr;
 ptr = (byte*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)byte_array.Length);
 Marshal.Copy(byte_array, 0, (IntPtr)ptr, byte_array.Length);
```

Comment: Please be a bit specific - what doesn't work? Doesn't it compile, compiles, but crashes, the result is wrong etc?

Comment: no, everything is compiled, no exceptions are thrown, but the function returns the wrong result

Comment: If you can't make byte[] work then byte* won't work either.  You have to post more code to help us help you.

Comment: it fulfills the array with the definite values. If the size of array is less than needed(10), it returns false. If I create an array of 3 elements, it still returns true.

Comment: I'm passing it as a second parameter, thought it's not meaningful in this case, will add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to marshal the `byte[]` :

```
[DllImport("YourNativeDLL.dll")]
public static extern void native_function
(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    byte[] data,
    int count // Recommended
);
```

Comment: LPArray is the default marshaling, this is unlikely to help the OP.

Answer (score 6):

```
unsafe class Test
{
    public byte* PointerData(byte* data, int length)
    {
        byte[] safe = new byte[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            safe[i] = data[i];

        fixed (byte* converted = safe)
        {
            // This will update the safe and converted arrays.
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                converted[i]++;

            return converted;
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to set the "use unsafe code" checkbox in the build properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could allocate an unmanaged array and use [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146625.aspx) to copy the contents of the managed `byte[]` array to an unmanaged `unsigned char*` array. Note that unmanaged resources must be cleaned up manually.